# bigquery api の run_sync_query() メソッドのパラメータ "query_parameter" が機能しない?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

--
python/google-cloud-bigquery==0.27.0 利用し client.run_sync_query() APIのquery_parameters を利用してみたのだが、バインド変数(`@table_prefix`)が置換されない。スタックトレースを見る限り機能していないように見えるが、コードとして何か不備があるのか？

--
i tried to call run_sync_query api with query_parameters using python with google-cloud-bigquery==0.27.0.
I got error.
it seems it's not working.
According to stack-trace
the bind variable(@table_prefix) was kept without replacing values.
what should i fix my script?

myscript.py

```
query="""
#standardSQL
select _table_suffix as suf from `dataset.@table_prefix*`
where _table_suffix = '20171030'
"""
query_parameters=[
ScalarQueryParameter('table_prefix', 'STRING', mytable)
]
result = self.client.run_sync_query(query=query, \
query_parameters=query_parmeters)
result.run()
```

### stacktrace

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/query.py", line 387, in run
    method='POST', path=path, data=self._build_resource())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 293, in api_request
    raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
BadRequest: 400 POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects//queries: Invalid table name: dataset.@table_prefix*
```

--
"dataset" has table "mytable20171030".

Comment: スタックオーバーフローへようこそ！日本語追記していただき、ありがとうございます。よろしければ、タイトルも日本語に変換していただけますでしょうか？（タイトルは、トップページからも表示されるので、日本語で記述されている方が望ましく。。）

Comment: 解決
where句などに使えるが from句には利用できないようです。
--
Resolved
it's Working but it was different to I expected.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/pull/2776

Comment: よろしければ、問題が解決した場合には、それを回答として投稿していただけますでしょうか？質問・回答形式で情報を集約・整理するようにデザインされているのがスタックオーバーフローなので。。